# Class implementations in __init__.py

Tags: python

I have been looking into `__init__.py` files, and see the recommendation is to handle the imports for the package there, and/or some initialization.

Then there is a package like Python [Collections](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/__init__.py). That `__init__.py` contains the implementations for different Collection objects.

Why would you place implementations in the `__init__.py` instead of dedicated `.py` files within the package? Is this a good idea? Is it a design pattern?

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, there's no need to have a directory with an `__init__.py` file at all, since the only other file in that module is [`abc.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/abc.py), which defines nothing itself. So if it weren't for `abc.py`, the entire thing should just be `collections.py` instead of `collections/__init__.py`. So why is it what it is? Purely for backwards compatibility reasons. They did not want to break `from collections.abc import ...`, but wanted to move stuff around internally.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts in general, not about this particular case of `collections`?

Comment: It's generally not a terrible idea IMO. You only want to be careful with circular imports, e.g. when a sub-module imports some base classes from `__init__.py`, but `__init__.py` also imports those submodules to expose them.